# Is saying "can you do this for me" rude?

Tags: politeness

I recently got into a conversation with a freind who said it's rude to directly ask people without using the word "please" or converting the question to an indirect one. In the US this is the norm and I seem to have seen countless people using it on a day to day basis.

> Can I get a fry?
>
> Can I have a cup of tea?

Comment: Depends on where you are, even in the US, and perhaps, your equation with the person whom you are asking.

Comment: All answers/comments will be opinions rather than facts on questions such as this. I (from England)  always use *please* for a first request, and rather feel that people making a request of me are being a little offhand if they don't say *please*. If somebody is helping me and I make a series of requests such as 'Pass the hammer', 'Give me another nail, 'Turn that knob', etc, I would not worry too much about the *please*s every time.

Comment: I'm not sure how *Can I get a fry?* translates into the Queen's English. It sounds positively obscene to me. 'Could I have a cup of tea?' sounds far pleasanter than 'Can...'. And it's even better if you add *please*.

Comment: I'd say the norm is *Yo B lemme get some fries*.  No one says *may I have* nothin'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about manners, not about English language or usage.

Comment: There's a typo: friend

Comment: As for the question, it used to be considered grammatical and polite to ask: **May I** *partake in your portion of fries?*

Comment: @ColinFine I don't understand why *politeness* isn't part of usage? It seems to me to be another aspect of things such as style and register.

Comment: @Araucaria: I suppose it is, in a way; but to me pleases and thank yous seem not to be part of the language, but of something else.

Comment: If pleases and thank yous are not part of the language, my mind is officially boggled.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the word *please* out of a question is not rude. Leaving it out of a command or statement *is*.

It is rude to begin a conversation with a stranger or ask a question without saying *excuse me*. Direct questioning is fine once we've said *hello*.

There are levels of curtness the working world expects; I'm going to look at you funny for a second before I answer your question of "*Excuse me, hello. I was wondering if you could tell me what time it is, please*?" I wouldn't if you just asked "*Hey, what time is it*?"

Comment: +1 for the "Excuse me, hello. I was wondering if you could tell me what time it is, please?" example :)

Comment: @Mazure. *Excuse me, hello. I was wondering if you could tell me what time it is, please? is excessive, but I would consider *Hey, what time is it?* rather impolite.

Comment: It'd be considered rude if you don't say *thank you* afterwards. Have the courtesy to thank them for their time without wasting any of it while asking for it. It's by the bounds of standard etiquette *impolite*; it only becomes *rude* when someone becomes offended.

Comment: 'excuse me, hello'  would personally rub me the wrong way. The 'Excuse me' already serves to draw my attention. The 'hello' would suggest (depending on how quickly it would follow the 'excuse me') that the speaker is rushing me, like a sarcastic '**nów** do I have your attention?'. I would leave the 'hello' out of the question or start the question with it (if the other party were already looking at you for some reason).